# subscribing takes too long for users to wait on webpage for confirmation... solutions?

Tags: c#, .net

On our .NET 3.5 website in c# a user clicks submit on our webpage, they are subscribed by email address to our reports.  Unfortunately, this action takes about 5 minutes and the user has to sit and wait for confirmation.  What I would like to do is change it so that when they click submit, they get a pop up that says they will be notified by email when their subscription goes through, meanwhile i would queue up the subscribe action somewhere else on the server so that it doesnt exist in the web code.  Can you give me some ways to do this? The basic idea is that I want to split  into two different lines of execution where one will allow them to still browse our website and the other will subscribe them.  I was thinking split into a new thread but I think that the web code would still have to wait for that thread to finish before they could do anything else.  I'm looking for ideas, preferably something that can run on the same server. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's many options, but the basic approach will be to decouple the site from the provider.  Instead you'll write out a record saying "User X is waiting to subscribe", a seperate process will then read the record and perform the actual subscription, while marking the record as "in-progress".  Once the process has complete the record will again be updated with the completed information.

You can achieve this with databases, message queues, or other approaches.  But fundamentally your site will only be responsible for creating the record and checking it's status--the actual interaction with the provider will be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that takes this long and you want to true and ensure the action goes through, then your best bet is going to be to queue it up.

Basically, when they submit the request, store that in a database table and let them move on.  Meanwhile, have another process that monitors that table to process the requests.  When they come in just have this second process send the request on to the part that takes 5 minutes to complete.

Once it finishes, send them a "welcome to such and such email list" message.  That will serve as their confirmation that it worked.

Comment: when you say 'process' you just mean write another program running on the server, right? there isnt anything special about a process?

Comment: @milly: that's exactly what I mean.  Another program: usually a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Atwood blogged on a relevant topic here a while back.  Since you are using c#, I assume you're using ASP.NET and can take advantage of the cache mechanisms to kick off a periodic worker job.  On the user's request, you can persist details of the subscription to some data store.  In that job, you can examine the queue to determine what subscriptions need to be created and then execute them.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/